# Undefined index: _attribute_set in magento product csv import from admin

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am importing an products csv from magento admin then it is showing me an error when i click on import button after check data.

> **Notice**: Undefined index: _attribute_set in /home/deleshop/public_html/v2/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php
>   on line 1394

some product sample data is:

```
"sku","manufacturer_code","model","type_code","kba","category_code","mounting_space","part_number","reference_number","designation","custom_thumbnail","custom_image","price","note1","note2","supplier_id","_category","_root_category","_attribute_set","_type","_product_websites","custom_design","msrp_display_actual_price_type","msrp_enabled","name","options_container","status","visibility","weight","qty","use_config_min_qty","use_config_backorders","min_sale_qty","use_config_min_sale_qty","max_sale_qty","use_config_max_sale_qty","is_in_stock","notify_stock_qty","use_config_notify_stock_qty","manage_stock","use_config_manage_stock","use_config_qty_increments","use_config_enable_qty_inc"
"20M1","20","4368","16366","1004536","10190","","1","","anlasser Chrysler Neon Ii (pl2000) 1.6  85 Kw  116 Ps (11.2001-12.2006)","","","120,00","Anlasser Chrysler Neon Ii (pl2000) 1.6  85 Kw  116 Ps (11.2001-12.2006)"," laufleistung: 92300 Kmt<br>typen:<br>  Chrysler Neon Ii (pl2000) 1.6  85 Kw  116 Ps (11.2001-12.2006)<br>kba: 1004536<br>   ","","","Root Catalog","Default","simple","base","default/galarainbow","Use config","Use config","anlasser Chrysler Neon Ii (pl2000) 1.6  85 Kw  116 Ps (11.2001-12.2006)","Block after Info Column","1","4","1","1","1","1","1","1","1000","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","MOTOR","Root Catalog","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","MOTOR/Startmotor","Root Catalog","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"20M3","20","4368","16366","1004536","10230","","3","","lichtmaschine Chrysler Neon Ii (pl2000) 1.6  85 Kw  116 Ps (11.2001-12.2006)","","","135,00","Lichtmaschine Chrysler Neon Ii (pl2000) 1.6  85 Kw  116 Ps (11.2001-12.2006)"," laufleistung: 92300 Kmt<br>typen:<br>  Chrysler Neon Ii (pl2000) 1.6  85 Kw  116 Ps (11.2001-12.2006)<br>kba: 1004536<br>   ","","","Root Catalog","Default","simple","base","default/galarainbow","Use config","Use config","lichtmaschine Chrysler Neon Ii (pl2000) 1.6  85 Kw  116 Ps (11.2001-12.2006)","Block after Info Column","1","4","1","1","1","1","1","1","1000","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","MOTOR","Root Catalog","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","MOTOR/Dynamo","Root Catalog","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

Comment: Any progress on this ? I have the same issue on Magento EE 1.14.0.1

Comment: no progress. i have export product and import same exported file this is working fine. but my product csv showing this error.

Comment: This is working for me now. Please set _attribute_set value in all row  "Default".

Answer (score 1):

Repeat the Attribute set value in all rows (keep the header : **_attribute_set**), it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it didn't work :/ I only have 2 products (I'm testing)

Answer (score 0):

Change `_attribute_set` in the first row to `attribute_set` and try to import again.

Comment: This is working for me now. Please set _attribute_set value in all row "Default"

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me now. ***Please set _attribute_set value in all row "Default"***
Like in above example default not set in these 2 rows-

```
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","MOTOR","Root Catalog","Default","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","" "","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","MOTOR/Dynamo","Root Catalog","Default","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this file `/home/deleshop/public_html/v2/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php`

Add the following code before line with error:

```
if (!empty($rowData['_attribute_set'])) {
    $_SESSION['_attribute_set'] = $rowData['_attribute_set'];
} elseif(!empty($_SESSION['_attribute_set'])){
    $rowData['_attribute_set'] = $_SESSION['_attribute_set'];
}
```